# How to show time ago in javascript (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Actually I have a date time or time-stamp format looks like **2015-12-18 07:10:54** this time should be converted or modified by like 2 hours ago or else.

I have tried this one. but there is something wrong with this.

Always showing 8 days ago. {which is wrong estimation.}

```
function ( date ) {

    var seconds = Math.floor(( new Date() - date ) / 1000 );

    var interval = Math.floor( seconds / 31536000 );

    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " year ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " years ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 2592000 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " month ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " months ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 86400 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " day ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " days ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 3600 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " hour ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " hours ago";
    }

    interval = Math.floor( seconds / 60 );
    if ( interval == 1 ) {

        return interval + " minute ago";
    }
    if ( interval > 1 ) {

        return interval + " minutes ago";
    }

    return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds ago";
}
```

Comment: The easy solution would be to use something like momentJS.

Comment: Use MomentJS https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: Do you have a proper JS timestamp or is `2015-12-18 07:10:54` all you've got? Because parsing an identified format for a timestamp is far easier than parsing an arbitrary one.

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) that's a powerful library to manage dates, install it with :

```
npm install --save moment
```

And then you simply get the time from now as:

```
moment().fromNow();
```

Or

```
var yourDate = new Date();
moment(yourDate).fromNow();
```

Or as per your example:

```
moment("2015-12-18 07:10:54", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

If you have a date in ISO format like that below, you don't need to format it, just use it:

```
moment("2015-12-09T12:09:30.000Z").fromNow()
```

Comment: thats preety good. but giving me Invalid Date. Actually In my database time is saved as and if i fetch that time , then it print look like 2015-12-09T12:09:30.000Z , so how to format this date?? :o

Comment: You don't need to format that date because it's the standard one so just do: `moment("2015-12-09T12:09:30.000Z").fromNow()` Output: `9 days ago`

Comment: view : 2015-12-09T12:09:30.000Z
but database : 2015-12-18 07:10:54  , how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) this kind of operation become simple as:

```
moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar(); // 12/08/2015
moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();  // Last Saturday at 10:10 AM
moment().subtract(3, 'days').calendar();  // Last Tuesday at 10:10 AM
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();  // Yesterday at 10:10 AM
moment().calendar();                      // Today at 10:10 AM
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();       // Tomorrow at 10:10 AM
moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();       // Monday at 10:10 AM
moment().add(10, 'days'
```

Comment: I tried moment("2015-12-18 07:10:54", "yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss").fromNow(); but returns "3 months ago".

Comment: try with this `moment("2015-12-18 07:10:54").format("YYYY-mm-dd h:MM:ss");`

Comment: It should be `moment("2015-12-18 07:10:54", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow();` check my answer

Comment: It's definitely as @Michelem said in his answer

Answer (score 0):

> this time should be converted or modified by like 2 hours ago or else

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var dateFromString = new Date('2015-12-18 07:10:54');

result.textContent = 'dateFromString: ' + dateFromString;

// dateFromString: travel 2 hours back
dateFromString.setHours(dateFromString.getHours()-2);
result.textContent += '\n2 hours before 2015-12-18 07:10:54: ' + 
                       dateFromString;


// determine difference between 2015-12-18 07:10:54 and the (time traveled) dateFromString
var difference = dateDiffCalc([new Date('2015-12-18 07:10:54'), dateFromString])
result.textContent += '\nHours difference dateFromString and '+
                      '2015-12-18 07:10:54: ' +
                      difference.hours;

function dateDiffCalc(value) {
  var ms = Math.abs(value[0].getTime()-value[1].getTime());
  var secsdf = Math.floor(((ms/1000)%(60*60))%60);
  var mindf  = Math.floor((ms/(60*1000))%60);
  var hourdf = Math.floor(ms/(60*1000*60)%24);
  var daydf  = Math.round((ms/(60*1000*60))/24);
  return {
    days: daydf,
    hours: hourdf,
    minutes: mindf,
    seconds: secsdf
  };
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I'd agree moment for this use-case is far too heavy, something like this is far more workable for this problem. This solution does require a proper JS timestamp however, and the question does not show that that is a given. It looks like the actual problem is parsing from an irregular timestamp into one that JS understands. I'm not sure moment helps there either. Getting a proper timestamp should be the correct answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, by using the Moment API you can achieve that very easily.

```
// Get the Time Since Content was Posted with Moment.js
  const getDate = (date) => {
    const dateTime = new Date(date * 1000);
    return moment(dateTime).fromNow();
  };
```

`date` is the UTC timestamp